# How to transform a matrix with 2 columns into a multimap like structure?

Tags: list, r, arrays, multimap

I am wondering if there is a way to transform a matrix of 2 columns into a multimap or list of list.

The first column of the matrix is an id (with possibly duplicated entries) and the 2nd column is some value.

For example,
if I have to following matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3,2,4), c(3,2))
```

I would like to transform it into the following list

```
[[1]]
3,4
[[2]]
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base functions, you can do something like this:

```
tapply(m[,2], m[,1], `[`)        # outputs an array
by(m, m[,1], function(m) m[,2])  # outputs a by object, which is a list
```

You could use `plyr`:

```
dlply(m, 1, function(m) m[,2])   # outputs a list
dlply(m, 1, `[`, 2)              # another way to do it...
```

Comment: As of today, the `plyr` approaches don't return the expected result.